# Jquery input text change show/hide select options

Tags: jquery

I have the problems to show/hide select options when input text change.
I have created an example [here]: http://jsfiddle.net/gr09tkwb/

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="f1" id="f1" />
<select name="f2" id="f2">
<option>Select</option>
<option id="id1">id1</option>
<option id="id2">id2</option>
<option id="id3">id3</option>
<option id="id4">id4</option>
</select>
```

Here is the script:

```
$("#f1").on("change",function(){
var e=$("#f2").val();
var t=$("#f1").val();
var n=8.25;
var r=2.5;
var i=.5;
var s=t>10;
var u=t>n&&t<=10;
var a=t>r&&t<=n;
var f=t<=r&&t>i;
if(s){
    $("#id2,#id3,#id4").remove().end();
    $('<option id="id1">id1</option>').appendTo(s)
}else if(u){
    $("#id3,#id4").remove().end();
    $('<option id="id1">id1</option><option id="id2">id2</option>').appendTo(u)
}else if(a){
    $("#id4").remove().end();
    $('<option id="id1">id1</option><option id="id2">id2</option><option id="id3">id3</option>').appendTo(a)
}else if(f){
    $().remove().end();
    $('<option id="id1">id1</option><option id="id2">id2</option><option id="id3">id3</option><option id="id4">id4</option>').appendTo(f)
}
});
```

When I enter number 20, which is 's' (greater than 10), select option shows id1. Good.

When I enter number 9, which is 'u' (greater than 8.25 && <= 10), select option still shows id1.

But, load the page and enter number 9, it shows id1 AND id2, which is correct. Now enter number 20 again, it shows id1 only. It seems to work just fine.

The problem:

when enter a number that is greater than the number I entered previously, it works; but if entering a number that is less than the number entered previously, nothing changes.

Please take a look, thanks.

Comment: can you post the purpose of the program?

Comment: Hi, it's a box selector based on weight input.

Comment: we need more details, what are the use cases? scenarios to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with your script that's breaking things (though, it appears to work).

In your four if conditions, this line:

```
$("#id2,#id3,#id4").remove().end();
```

"works" as you intend. Although the `end` method call is not needed, since you're not continuing to chain.

So, for all four if conditions, it will always properly remove the `options` queried in the selector.

Following that, you have a line that looks like this:

```
if(s){
    ...
    $('<option id="id1">id1</option>').appendTo(s)
}
```

These are incorrect. `appendTo` expects a target (selector, jquery object, etc) to append the string of HTML to. You're passing the boolean true to appendTo, so it's never actually appending the changes.

Basically, It'll always remove - just never update.

To fix it, I made the following change:

Before the if statement, we just remove all `option` elements (except the first one)

```
$('#f2').find('option:not(:eq(0))').remove();
```

After, we query the `select` statement and append the string of HTML.

```
if(s){
    $('#f2').append('<option id="id1">id1</option>');
}else if(u){
    $('#f2').append('<option id="id1">id1</option><option id="id2">id2</option>');
}else if(a){
    $('#f2').append('<option id="id1">id1</option><option id="id2">id2</option><option id="id3">id3</option>');
}else if(f){
    $('#f2').append('<option id="id1">id1</option><option id="id2">id2</option><option id="id3">id3</option><option id="id4">id4</option>');
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gr09tkwb/2/

Comment: No problem @John. I actually made one small change - which was to filter out the very first <option>Select</option>. `find('option:not(:eq(0))')` The answer was updated to reflect it.